# Null Pointer Exception at 'if' statement

Tags: java, android, exception, if-statement, nullpointerexception

Im getting furious, because Im still getting an error at my code:

```
myVar = getFiles();
(...)
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getFiles(){
    File dir = new File(new String("/sdcard/"));

    if (dir.listFiles(new myFilter()).length > 0) {
        for (File file : dir.listFiles(new myFilter())) {
            (...)
        }
    }
    return myList;
}
```

at if statement:

```
if (dir.listFiles(new myFilter()).length > 0) {
```

This is what i get:

```
01-13 22:28:42.313: W/dalvikvm(13776): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c5a1f8)
01-13 22:28:42.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13776): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-13 22:28:42.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13776): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.remotedevice/com.example.remotedevice.Player}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-13 22:28:42.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13776):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
01-13 22:28:42.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13776):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
01-13 22:28:42.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13776):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
01-13 22:28:42.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13776):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
01-13 22:28:42.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13776):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-13 22:28:42.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13776):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-13 22:28:42.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13776):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
01-13 22:28:42.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13776):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-13 22:28:42.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13776):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-13 22:28:42.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13776):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
01-13 22:28:42.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13776):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
01-13 22:28:42.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13776):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-13 22:28:42.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13776): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-13 22:28:42.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13776):    at com.example.remotedevice.Player.getPlayList(Player.java:120)
01-13 22:28:42.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13776):    at com.example.remotedevice.Player.onCreate(Player.java:56)
01-13 22:28:42.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13776):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
01-13 22:28:42.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13776):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
01-13 22:28:42.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13776):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
01-13 22:28:42.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13776):    ... 11 more
```

I've read this topic : [Null Pointer Exception after checking with 'if' statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405902/null-pointer-exception-after-checking-with-if-statement) but havent find answear, which I could use to my code :/ I've tried few 'solutions' but still getting this error :( PLEASE HELP!

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-13 22:28:42.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13776):    at com.example.remotedevice.Player.getPlayList(Player.java:120)`  Which line, exactly, is 120?

Comment: as i said:
"at if statement: if (dir.listFiles(new myFilter()).length > 0) {"
(this is line 120)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`File` `listFiles()` may return `null` for example if the file is not a directory. You'll need to check for `!= null` before accessing the `length` field to prevent the NPE.

Now, why isn't `/sdcard` a directory? On many devices it is a symbolic link. You'll have to resolve the symbolic link with `getCanonicalFile()` first.

Example:

```
File[] files = dir.getCanonicalFile().listFiles(new myFilter());
if (files != null) {   
    for (File file : files) {
        //...
```

Also, it's beneficial to store the result of an "expensive" method call such as `listFiles()` instead of calling it repeatedly.

Comment: I think the OP wants to know why it is returning null

Comment: The problem was that I gave directory "/dir" instead of "/sdcard/dir"... But I saw that after your post about "symbolic link" - thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for the [listFiles()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29), it "Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs."

Therefore, you will need to check if it is null and handle the error in these situations.